# How do I assign an object to an array within another object?

Tags: javascript

I'm taking on the blackjack challenge and coming up with my own code. So here's what I've got so far ... my card generator ...

```
var card = {
    suit: null,
    face: null,
    value: null,
    generateSuit: function (x) {
        if (x == 0) this.suit = 'Clubs';
        if (x == 1) this.suit = 'Diamonds';
        if (x == 2) this.suit = 'Hearts';
        if (x == 3) this.suit = 'Spades';
    },
    generateFace: function (y) {
        if (y > 1 && y < 11) this.face = y,
        this.value = y;
        else {
            if (y == 1) this.face = 'Ace', this.value = 1;
            if (y == 11) this.face = 'Jack', this.value = 10;
            if (y == 12) this.face = 'Queen', this.value = 10;
            if (y == 13) this.face = 'King', this.value = 10;
        };
    },
    generateCard: function () {
        var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13 + 1);
        this.generateSuit(x);
        this.generateFace(y);
    },
}
```

This works fine, I'm just including it because the next part has me stumped so I figured I'd leave nothing out.

Here's where things go south - within my 'hand' (posted next), I'm using my 'generateCard()' function to set the values of 'card' and then store them in an array named 'storecard [ ]'.

```
var hand = {
    storecard: [],
    count: 0,
    total: 0,
    hitCard: function () {
        this.count += 1;
        card.generateCard();
        this.storecard[this.count] = Object.create(card);
        this.total += this.storecard[this.count].value;
        this.logHand();
    },
    logHand: function () {
        console.log(this.storecard[this.count].face + ' of ' + this.storecard[this.count].suit);
        console.log('Value = ' + this.storecard[this.count].value);
        console.log('Count = ' + this.count);
        console.log('Hand Total = ' + this.total);
    }
}
```

The idea being that every time a card is hit (added to the hand), 'hand' will stash it (and all of its properties - suit, value, etc.) in `storecard[index == hand count, clever eh?]`

This way, I can retrieve any attribute of any card in the hand whenever and however I please by accessing `storecard[index]`.

Well, not so much. Run the code and that array is the only thing that bites the dust...

```
var me = Object.create(hand);
var dealer = Object.create(hand);

me.hitCard();
me.hitCard();
```

My 'logHand()' function indicates all is well!

```
"5 of Hearts"     
"Value = 5"       
"Count = 1"       
"Hand Total = 5"  
"2 of Clubs"      
"Value = 2"       
"Count = 2"       
"Hand Total = 7"
```

But alas, somehow - the 'storecard' array has failed. Upon further examination we discover:

```
me.storecard[1].value
2
me.storecard[2].value
2
```

`storecard[1]` should be holding my 5 of hearts, but has been overwritten by the 2 of clubs! And if that isn't horrifying enough ...

```
dealer.storecard[1].value
2
dealer.storecard[1].value
2
```

I haven't even touched the dealer object yet!

Now every other variable in both my hand and the dealer hand are congruent with reality - the array is the only problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to understand how references work. If you create an object that is **referenced** in multiple other objects it will be updated and changed every time it is modified anywhere in your code in every object it is referenced in. In essence only one of this object exists in memory and is **referenced** in multiple places. A very powerful tool if used well, a very very confusing concept if misunderstood.

Comment: If you're bored, walk me through it - there are only two objects in question and the only thing afoul is the array

Comment: As Andrew pointed out in his answer below, when you use `Object.create()` you are doing exactly this, referencing the same object to different variables. The following statement would evaluate true : `me === dealer`.

Comment: Trying to wrap my mind around it - I see what you and andrew are saying, just not soaking in the array angle. me === dealer returns false ... me.storecard === dealer.storecard returns true

Comment: Apologies, last comment meant to say `me.storecard === dealer.storecard`. This is because arrays are stored by reference, and `Object.create` creates shallow clones, meaning any properties that are assigned by reference, ie arrays, will be created by reference to the cloned object. What you really want to do is not shallow clone the object but create a brand new one each time you ask for it. Doing what Andrew suggests below will help, by having your object returned from a function call you are no longer creating this reference each time you create it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well this is a different approach but a good way to do it.
i've written the code in a way you could learn something.
as example.. you could fully get rid of the count variable since its equal to storecard.length.
mind however that you still need to prevent dublicate cards. you can easily do it by generating all cards first, putting it into an array and then splicing cards out of it randomly untill the stack is empty.

```
var Card = function () {
    this.suit = null;
    this.face = null;
    this.value = null;
    this.generateCard();
};

Card.prototype = {
    generateSuit: function (x) {
        this.suit = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"][x];
    },
    generateFace: function (y) {
        this.value = Math.min(10, y);
        switch (y) {
            case 1:
                this.face = "Ace";
                break;
            case 11:
                this.face = "Jack";
                break;
            case 12:
                this.face = "Queen";
                break;
            case 13:
                this.face = "King";
                break;
            default:
                this.face = y;
                break;
        }
    },
    generateCard: function () {
        this.generateSuit(Math.floor(Math.random() *4));
        this.generateFace(Math.floor(Math.random() *13 +1));
    }
}

var Hand = function () {
    this.storecard = [];
    this.count = 0;
    this.total = 0;
};

Hand.prototype = {
    hitCard: function () {
        this.count++;
        var card = new Card();
        this.storecard.push(card);
        this.total += card.value;
        this.logHand();
    },
    logHand: function () {
        var card = this.storecard[this.storecard.length -1];
        console.log(card.face + ' of ' + card.suit);
        console.log('Value = ' + card.value);
        console.log('Count = ' + this.count);
        console.log('Hand Total = ' + this.total);
    }
}
```

outcome will be:

```
> var me = new Hand();
undefined
> var dealer = new Hand();
undefined
> me.hitCard();
Ace of Hearts
Value = 1
Count = 1
Hand Total = 1
undefined
> me.hitCard();
6 of Diamonds
Value = 6
Count = 2
Hand Total = 7
undefined
> me.storecard
[ { suit: 'Hearts',
    face: 'Ace',
    value: 1 },
  { suit: 'Diamonds',
    face: 6,
    value: 6 } ]
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is your expectation of what `Object.create()` does.

It creates a shallow clone of the object. Arrays are assigned by reference, not value.

For example

```
var arrayOne = [];
var arrayTwo = arrayOne;
arrayOne.push('3');
alert(arrayTwo[0]); // This will give you 3. Both variables are pointing to the same array
```

So too:

```
   var handTemplate = {
       childArray: []
   };

   var handOne = Object.create(handTemplate);
   var handTwo = Object.create(handTemplate);
   // At this point, handTemplate, handOne and handTwo all point to the same array

   handOne.childArray.push('3');
   alert(handTwo.childArray([0])); // Again, you'll see 3, because there's only one array
```

One solution is to create `hand` using a dedicated function:

```
function createHand() {
    return {
        storecard: [], // Now we get a brand new array every time createHand is called
        count: 0,
        total: 0,
        hitCard: function () {
            this.count += 1;
            card.generateCard();
            this.storecard[this.count] = Object.create(card);
            this.total += this.storecard[this.count].value;
            this.logHand();
        },
        logHand: function () {
            console.log(this.storecard[this.count].face + ' of ' + this.storecard[this.count].suit);
            console.log('Value = ' + this.storecard[this.count].value);
            console.log('Count = ' + this.count);
            console.log('Hand Total = ' + this.total);
        }
    };
}

var me     = createHand();
var dealer = createHand();
```

Comment: ahhhh, i think it's beginning to click. in this scenario is `Object.create(card)` even necessary? would `this.storecard[this.count] = card` suffice?

Comment: odd - it does not make a difference whether or not the array = `card` or `Object.create(card)` - the results are the same - and i'm still lost because your solution produces the same results my original code does (it does solve the dealer sharing the array, but it doesn't solve `storecard[1]` being overwritten by `storecard[2]`)